# jQuery add to HEAD with variable (Unexpected String Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with creating a concatenating string in Javascript

With the below code I receive an error: Unexpected string.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var bgcolor = $('.ls-background--stretch').css('background-color');
    alert(bgcolor);
    var bgheight = $('.ls-background--stretch').height();
    alert(bgheight);
    $('head').append('<style type="text/css">.ls-background--stretch {  position: relative;}   .ls-background--stretch::before {  content: "";  position: absolute;  left: -50%;  top: 0;  width: 1000%;  z-index: 0;  height: '.bgheight.'px;  background-color: '.bgcolor.';}</style>');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This has no doubt to do with the `height: '.bgheight.'px;` and the color that comes after it.

I made a Codepen for it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJddgR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css">.ls-background--stretch {  position: relative;}   .ls-background--stretch::before {  content: "";  position: absolute;  left: -50%;  top: 0;  width: 1000%;  z-index: 0;  height: '+ bgheight +'px;  background-color: '+ bgcolor +';}</style>');
```

Add `"+"` instead of `"."`. In JavaScript for concatenating string we use `"+"` and in php we use `"."`

Comment: Ohhh dang thats it.... How incredibly stupid of me.... And then looking for 30 minutes to it and not seeing it. I am kicking myself under my *** right now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome @purple11111